# Home phone over cat 6 in patch panel?

Tags: home-networking, voice, patch-panel

So here is my question.

I am building my new home and I'm putting in ethernet for poe APs and I already called the phone company and they are fine with cat 6 for the phone and data connection.  Right now it's DSL so I have to have a home phone, so I was thinking can I run the cat6 for the voice line into a patch panel (same patch panel I have for my data devices) and then use a patch cable to connect it to the port where I want the phone?  My reason for doing this is that if they ever drop the requirement for home phone or we get cellular home internet service I can switch the port over to a data port and use google voice.

In other words, if I put both lines from the telco into ports 1 and 2 on the patch panel, and the phone in the kitchen is in port 3 on the patch panel, can I connect port 2 (voice) to port 3 (kitchen phone) with a patch cable?  or would i need a crossover?  or would this not work at all?

I think it would work fine, but I want a sanity check.

Comment: Patch panels are quite common.  Mine, at home has over 50 connections.  For a start it is easier to wire in a new house,  Just run everything to the AV rack.  And later patch it to suit.